# MySQL ORDER BY 2 columns with exception

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

A problem with ordering a search result by 2 columns.

My table: transit time is stored in seconds, appointment is time

```
id  transit_time appointment
----------------------------
 2  3845         09:00:00
11  22053        13:00:00
10  4852         08:00:00
11  5985         NULL 
13  7221         12:45:00
14  3812         NULL
17  4256         NULL
18  5663         NULL
19  4725         NULL
```

I want to make a select that order the records by:

**1.** appointment IS NULL at the end

**2.** by appointment time ASC

**3. if transit time is greater than appointment then that record should be on top of sorting at point 2**

For example the right order should be:

```
id  transit_time appointment
----------------------------
11  22053        13:00:00
13  10221        12:45:00
10  3852         08:00:00 
 2  4245         09:00:00
11  5985         NULL
18  5663         NULL
19  4725         NULL
17  4256         NULL
14  3812         NULL
```

I've tried many sorts with CASE but no luck to get that order by. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN appointment IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) asc, 
transit_time desc
```

Comment: Your desired results dont match the sample data. you have a 10221 or a  3852 in transit_time Which I dont understand where it comes from.In the sqlfiddle data all appointments converted to second -  transit_time give values bigger than transit_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to seconds to make the comparison

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN time_appointment IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,
 transit_time DESC,
CASE WHEN transit_time > TIME_TO_SEC(time_appointment) THEN transit_time ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense but my sort is still wrong. Put the transit time on top but the appointment is from the biggest time to smaller.

Comment: @AdrianP. Put the sample data on sql fiddle so I can test it.

Comment: @AdrianP. In your desired results,the appointment time is descending.Is that wrong?

Comment: It is appointment time ascending but if the transit time is bigger should take over the appointment time E.g.: from 7am, 8am ,9am but 1 pm should be on top because the transit time 6h - appointment time 13pm is less than appointment time 7am

Comment: In the end, I have done this: ORDER BY CASE WHEN time_appointment IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, time_appointment - SEC_TO_TIME(transit_time) ASC" thank you for pointing me in the right direction.